# Как правильно обновить набор галереи fancybox 3 после обновления коллекции?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

После инициализации fancybox я удаляю один из элементов или добавляю в коллекцию (галерею). Но не происходит пересчёт количества.

В доке пишут:

`$.fancybox.getInstance().update();`

Это один из вариантов, проблема в том, что не находит update. getInstance возвращает false.

Есть альтернатива:

`$.fancybox.getInstance().Thumbs.update();`

Но нет никаких Thembs там.

Как-то по старинке `$([data-fancybox]).fancybox().update();` тоже не сработало

Answer (score 0):

В общем, с инициализацией через такой селектор никакие методы применять и не надо, всё само пересчитывает

```
$().fancybox({
        selector: '[data-fancybox="gallery"]', ...
```